# undefined reference to `__gcov_flush'

Tags: c++, flush, gcov

I am trying same,

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/suse-linux/135465-gcov-g.html

Code from the link,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void one(void);
void two(void);
void __gcov_flush(void);

int main(void)
{
  int i;

  while(true)
  {
        __gcov_flush();
        cout <<  "Enter a number(1-2), 0 to exit " << endl;
        cin >> i;

        if ( i == 1 )
           one();
        else if ( i == 2 )
           two();
        else if ( i == 0 )
           break;
        else
          continue;
  }
  return 0;
}

void one(void)
{ cout << "One is called" << endl; }

void two(void)
{ cout << "Two is called" << endl; }
```

but for me also it gives,

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x1d9): undefined reference to `__gcov_flush()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Tried the followings,

```
g++ -fprofile-arcs test.cpp
g++ -fprofile-arcs -g test.cpp
g++ -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g test.cpp
g++ -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g test.cpp -lgcov
```

I have also tried the "-lgcov" & "extern void __gcov_flush(void)" as mentioned in link above. I am currently on Ubuntu12.04 and g++ 4.6

So, I want to know if there is solution for this or gcov_flush doesnt work anymore.

Comment: Have you added `-fprofile-arcs` switch while compiling? I think it's required to link the library archive.

Comment: @SAM yes.. I have tried that. updated the ans with tried ways..

Comment: move the -lgcov to after the test.cpp. This is a link ordering issue

Comment: @Petesh.. Thanks but.. tried 'g++ -fprofile-arcs flushtest.cpp -lgcov' & 'g++ flushtest.cpp -lgcov'.. no luck..

Comment: The `__gcov_flush()` has been removed in GCC 11. You should use the documented `__gcov_dump()`. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-and-Optimization.html.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
void __gcov_flush();
```

Since the code is compiled as C++, this declares the existence of a **C++** function of that name. C++ functions are subject to name mangling, so the (C++) symbol is not found in the (C) link library, and the linker (rightfully) complains about it.

If you declare the function, declare it as a function with **C** linkage:

```
extern "C" void __gcov_flush();
```

This should do the trick.

---

Note the comment by Paweł Bylica -- `__gcov_flush()` has been removed in GCC 11, you should use [`__gcov_dump()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-and-Optimization.html).

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue changing the settings.

Test Project --> Build Settings

**Instrument Program Flow**  = **Yes**

Comment: He is on linux, not Mac.